# Kotlin For loop, a bit confused

Tags: for-loop, kotlin

So I'm currently still starting off with Kotlin and just went over for loops and the book I'm using has given a small example that you need to work out and give the value that will print but I don't really understand how they get the value.

```
`fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var x =0
    var y =20
    for (outer in 1..3) {
     for (inner in 4 downTo 2) {
        x += 6
        y++
        x += 3
        }
        y -= 2
    }
    println("$x $y")
}`
```

It prints out "81 23". Basically I just need to know the "for loop" the has the 1..3, what value is it counting

Comment: You can println() inside the inner loop printing both the outer and inner yourself to know whats happening :)

Comment: thanks that helped a lot in understanding whats running in the back

Answer (score 0):

for (outer in 1..3) will iterate from 1 to 3 (inclusive) and for (inner in 4 downTo 2) will iterate from 4 to 2 i.e 4,3,2.

See loops: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-for-py/loops.html

Answer (score 0):

First you enter the outer loop, then you enter the inner loop. At the time of entry, you have X = 0, Y = 20. The inner loop has 3 iterations, and in each x increases first by 3 and then by 6, and y by 1. Respectively, after 3 iterations, inner x = 27 and y = 23, after which you exit inner and y decreases by 2. Then you re-enter inner for the second time with the value x =27, y = 21, after 3 iterations x = 54, and y = 24. Then you exit the inner and reduce y by 2. Then you go through the last iteration of outer again passing inner 3 times with input data x = 54, y = 22. As a result, we get x = 81, y = 23

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).